# Accessing Certain Values in T-SQL Dependant on Certain Value Being Available

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that accesses certain information from a database so it can then be checked against a form in a webpage using Selenium.  The problem I've run into is that certain fields in the form are not required to be filled out, and they show up as NULL in the database. If this value is NOT NULL, I use it as the Primary Key in a Person table and access more information on that person.  Is there some way I can only access these pieces of information when the value is NOT NULL? This is a snippet of what I'm trying to use right now:

```
    SELECT QAPreparer.OrgName as [Client] FROM Folder 
    CASE WHEN @Preparer=NULL
        THEN left join Person QAPreparer ON dbo.ufGetPrsnPk(dbo.ufgetPrsnName(Folder.PreparerPrsn)) = QAPreparer.PrsnPk
        ELSE --do nothing
    END
```

The CASE condition is throwing an error in SQL, but I believe that even if I got the syntax correct, trying to access QAPreparer.OrgName would throw an error when the Person shows up as NULL in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use special syntax for Null values. Instead of `variable = null`, you must write `variable IS NUll`,  and you can't put a join inside a case statement, but you can put a case statement inside the On clause of a Join....  so yor sql query should be rewritten as this:

```
SELECT qp.OrgName as [Client] 
   From Folder f
     left join Person qp 
         ON qp.PrsnPk =
            CASE WHEN @Preparer Is NULL 
                 Then dbo.ufGetPrsnPk(dbo.ufgetPrsnName(f.PreparerPrsn))
                 else null end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else condition.. something like below..

```
IF ISNULL(@Preparer,'')=''
BEGIN 
 SELECT QAPreparer.OrgName as [Client] 
 FROM Folder 
   LEFT JOIN Person QAPreparer 
      ON dbo.ufGetPrsnPk(dbo.ufgetPrsnName(Folder.PreparerPrsn)) = QAPreparer.PrsnPk
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT QAPreparer.OrgName as [Client] FROM Folder 
END
```